# How to get videoId of the video a stream will become (afterwards) from the StreamNow default broadcast?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Using the YouTube Stream Now API is there any way of getting the id of the video the Default Stream will be uploaded as (NOT DEFAULT STREAM ID), so you could create a url for it to be played ... youtube.com/watch?v=

Answer (score -2):

Both liveStream and LiveBroadcast are different things, according to the definition provided on youtube site. Hence the Id for them also should be different.

**[LiveStreams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams)**

> A liveStream resource contains information about the video stream that
>   you are transmitting to YouTube. The stream provides the content that
>   will be broadcast to YouTube users. Once created, a liveStream
>   resource can be bound to one or more liveBroadcast resources.

USING  `stream.getId()` you can get the ID of the video streaming

Sample code in the [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list#examples) gives the idea how to use it

**[LiveBroadcasts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts)**

> A liveBroadcast resource represents an event that will be streamed,
>   via live video, on YouTube.

USING  `returnedBroadcast.getId().getId()` you can get the ID of the Broadcast

Sample code in the [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/insert#try-it) gives the idea how to use it

Check the [Try It](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind#try-it) part in that there is streamId where you can specify which video you can bind with the broadcast.

Comment: so for the default broadcast they use the LiveStream id instead of the broadcastId.
That is weird behavior. That would mean that no LiveStream id could be the same as a BroadcastId.

Comment: I guess Yes, they may be using the LiveStream Id instead of the broadcast Id. Because the video stream will always be one, but they can be bound to one or more liveBroadcast resources. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: the stream id does not seem to be the video Id after the stream has finished is not correct. I know that LiveStream resource has an identifier attribute. I'm asking how to get the broadcast's or livestream's final video resource after streaming

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos